# Recommended 10Gb NIC in PCIe 4.0 1x slot?

Tags: networking, motherboard, network-adapter, bandwidth, pci-express

I've been trying to figure this out for some time, and lots of googling has seen lots of discussion but no actual answers that I can find.

I'm the happy owner of an AMD Ryzen system on an ASUS TUF GAMING X570-PLUS (WI-FI) motherboard, which has PCIe 4.0 enabled and working.

I want to purchase and install a 10Gb NIC, probably an SFP+ compatible card.

I'm quite aware that:

1. 10Gb NIC cards in a x1 format do not currently exist.
2. 10Gb NIC cards in x4 format exist.
3. PCIe x4 cards can be plugged into an PCIe x1 slot.
4. In my case, my PCIe 4.0 x1 slot is capable of 1.97GB/s or 15.76Gb/s.

What I'm trying to figure out is:

1. What is a recommended PCIe x4 10Gb NIC card I can use?
2. Can I plug an PCIe x4 10Gb NIC into my PCIe 4.0 x1 slot and get 10Gb NIC speed?
3. Will my motherboard simply negotiate the PCIe 4.0 x1 slot at PCIe 3.0 speed and halve the bandwidth to 985MB/s or 7.88Gb/s?

Has anyone used a 10Gb x4 NIC in an PCIe 4.0 x1 slot, and what was your experience?

Really hoping someone can help.

Comment: PCIe will work at the highest generation supported by *both* sides. A PCIe 3.0 card on a 4.0 motherboard will work at PCIe 3.0. The device will also work at the maximum amount of lanes available. A 3.0 x4 card in a 4.0 x1 socket will work at 3.0 x1 speeds. Product recommendations are off topic here.

Comment: Why has my question been closed?!
This is a question specifically about 10Gb NIC cards, which is a specific use case.

Comment: It was closed because it essentially duplicates previous questions asking about bandwidth differences between generations and speeds, and also is asking us to recommend a card to buy or use. By the numbers: 1) is an off topic product recommendation, 2) see previous duplicates (yes it will work, but caveats apply) 3) is also answered by inference from duplicates (i.e. yes it will limit to 3.0 x1 speeds if that is the highest available).

Comment: Most likely nobody will ever make one because 10Gbit/s requires over 2.5GB/s which a single lane of PCIe 4.0 cannot provide. What might happen is a PCIe 5.0 card is made, that will drop down to 4.0... but not implement the full duplex speed.

Comment: @cb88 why would 10Gbit/s require much more than 1.25GB/s? PCIe 4.0 x1 supports 2GB/s so to me it sounds perfectly feasible.

Comment: @Tom Honestly, yes, this is exactly what I am wondering.

Comment: I still don't think this specific question should be closed.
There is a valid discussion to be had regarding the specifics, feasibility, availability and usage of 10Gb NICs in PCI-E4.0 slots, which does not apply to other items like graphics cards etc.
Specific use cases that involve technologies such as SR-IOV is more prevalent in NICs also, and I think its a matter of time before a PCIe 4.0 x1 NIC is released.

Comment: @Tom because Ethernet is bidirectional. You actually need 2.5GB/s of PCIe bandwidth to implement it at Full Duplex.

Comment: Currently no PCIe 4.0 1x-4x nics exist except maybe at the extreme high end, so the best you are gonna do is 3.0, these are commonly PCIe 3.0 4x, you can also find cheap PCIe 2.0 8x cards. You can't get full bandwidth even half duplex out of a 3.0 1x link meaning that particular card configuration is super unlikely to exist, 10GB/s Ethernet requires 4x lanes to implement its full speed (technically 3 could do it but no boards implement that). Also a 1x PCIe 4.0 link would be enough for half duplex but not full... again meaning this is an unlikely configuration.